# Minimum steps to implement depth-only pass

Tags: opengl-es

I have an existing OpenGL ES 3.1 application that renders a scene to an FBO with color and depth/stencil attachment. It uses the usual methods for drawing (glBindBuffer, glDrawArrays, glBlend*, glStencil* etc. ). My task is now to create a depth-only pass that fills the depth attachment with the same values as the main pass.

My question is: What is the minimum number of steps necessary to achieve this and avoid the GPU doing superfluous work (unnecessary shader invocations etc.)? Is deactivating the color attachment enough or do I also have to set null shaders, disable blending etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need this before the main pass runs, otherwise you would just keep the main pass depth.

**Preflight**

1. Create specialized buffers which contain only the mesh data needed to compute position (which are deinterleaved from all non-position data).
2. Create specialized vertex shaders (which compute only the output position).
3. Link programs with the simplest valid fragment shader.

**Rendering**

1. Render the depth-only pass using the specialized buffers and shaders, masking out all color writes.
2. Render the main pass with the full buffers and shaders.

**Options**

At step (2) above it might be beneficial to load the depth-only pass depth results as the starting depth for the main pass. This will give you better early-zs test accuracy, at the expense of the readback of the depth value. Most mobile GPUs have hidden surface removal, so this isn't always going to be a net gain - it depends on your content, target GPU, and how good your front-to-back draw order is.

You probably want to use the specialized buffers (position data interleaved in one buffer region, non-position interleaved in a second)  for the main draw, as many GPUs will optimize out the non-position calculations if the primitive is culled.

The specialized buffers and optimized shaders can also be used for shadow mapping, and other such depth-only techniques.

Comment: Ok additional question: Will using glColorMask save me any of those steps (because if the shaders does not write frag depth, the driver should know that the fragment shader is trivial, right? )

Comment: For the fragment shader, yes, it's likely that using color masks would optimize that. Any pointless non-position stuff in the vertex shader is likely still going to get executed though. Just specialize - it's more development work, but its the "right" answer here and will improve run-time performance.